# Searching for variable amino acid motif in fasta dataset

Tags: python, biopython

I need to find out in which proteins of my dataset is this aminoacid motif: PoXGXXHyXHy. I'm using biopython and python 2.7, but I'm not exactly bioinformatician and I got stucked. How do I make something like seq_record + 1 or something like that? I've tried using in range, but it didn't work within SeqIO.parse. Well, I'm in this mess now, could someone help, please? I would be very thankful.

```
from Bio import SeqIO

print('enter the path to your fasta file: ' )
user_input = raw_input()

for seq_record in SeqIO.parse(user_input, "fasta"):

    aminoacids_count = len(seq_record)
    seq_record_trimmed = seq_record[aminoacids_count//2:aminoacids_count + 1]

    if 'R' or 'H' or 'K' or 'D' or 'E' or 'S' or 'T' or 'N' or 'Q' in seq_record_trimmed:
        if 'R' or 'H' or 'K' or 'D' or 'E' or 'S' or 'T' or 'N' or 'Q' or 'C' or 'U' or 'G' or 'P' or 'A' or 'V' or 'I' or 'L' or 'M' or 'F' or 'Y' or 'W' in seq_record_trimmed:
           if 'G' in seq_record_trimmed:
              if 'R' or 'H' or 'K' or 'D' or 'E' or 'S' or 'T' or 'N' or 'Q' or 'C' or 'U' or 'G' or 'P' or 'A' or 'V' or 'I' or 'L' or 'M' or 'F' or 'Y' or 'W' in seq_record_trimmed:
                if 'R' or 'H' or 'K' or 'D' or 'E' or 'S' or 'T' or 'N' or 'Q' or 'C' or 'U' or 'G' or 'P' or 'A' or 'V' or 'I' or 'L' or 'M' or 'F' or 'Y' or 'W' in seq_record_trimmed:
                    if 'A' or 'V' or 'I' or 'L' or 'M' or 'F' or 'W' or 'Y' in seq_record_trimmed:
                        if 'R' or 'H' or 'K' or 'D' or 'E' or 'S' or 'T' or 'N' or 'Q' or 'C' or 'U' or 'G' or 'P' or 'A' or 'V' or 'I' or 'L' or 'M' or 'F' or 'Y' or 'W' in seq_record_trimmed:
                            if 'A' or 'V' or 'I' or 'L' or 'M' or 'F' or 'W' or 'Y' in seq_record_trimmed:
                                print(seq_record.id)
                                continue
                            else:
                                break
                        else:
                            break
                    else:
                        break                                      
                else:
                    break                                  
            else:
                break                     
        else:
            break
    else:
        break
else:
    print(seq_record.id + 'No B_signal has been found')
```

Answer (score 0):

That's not going to work. You are better off using some regex.

```
from Bio import SeqIO
import re

print('enter the path to your fasta file: ' )
user_input = raw_input()    

Po = '[RHKDESTNQ]'
Hy = '[AVILMFWY]'
X = '.'

motif_pattern = Po + X + 'G' + X + X + Hy + X + Hy
motif_regex = re.compile(motif_pattern)

for seq_record in SeqIO.parse(user_input, "fasta"):

    aminoacids_count = len(seq_record)
    seq_record_trimmed = seq_record[aminoacids_count//2:aminoacids_count + 1]
    seq_str = str(seq_record_trimmed.seq)

    if motif_regex.search(seq_str):
        print(seq_record_trimmed.id)
```

`str(seq_record_trimmed.seq)` converts the sequence to a normal string. Before it was a Seq **object** with not all functionality for a string, like a regex search.

regex is a complete new topic in itself, independent of Python: It can be found in most programming languages. You can find explanations for it online. You can play around with regex on [regex101.com](https://regex101.com).

Next: `'R' or 'H' in seq_record` will not work as intended. It will always return True whatever seq_record might be. What you want is `'R' in seq_record or 'H' in seq_record`, or, if you don't want to repeat seq_record: `any(p in seq_record for p in 'RH')`.

Last: You control flow (if/else/break/continue) looks horrible and doesn't do what you intend with it. You should read more about how to write that properly.

Good luck.